# Gatsby - location.state 'Cannot read properties of null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

When I navigate from `/pageA` to `/pageB` I am passing a prop through Gatsby's Link to render UI information on PageB that I need from PageA.

If the user goes through the flow properly then the application works as expected. The problem happens when the user manually jumps to `/pageB` from a different page (i.e: changing url from `/home` to `/pageB`)

The navigation library that I'm using is `gatsby-plugin-transition-link` and I am passing the props following the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/) like so

```
<Link
 to={'/pageB'}
 state={{ fromPageA: true }}
>
```

My initial idea was if the prop returned null, then navigate back to the previous page cause then we know it didn't come from the correct page.

```
useEffect(() => {
 console.log(location.state.fromPageA);
 if (location.state.fromPageA === null) {
  navigate('/pageA')
 }
}, []);
```

The problem is that I can't even check for that because if I `console.log` it and it's null it immediately crashes my application with the error

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fromPageA')

Comment: Is the location destructured as a `prop`? Can you share that part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

I think what is breaking your current code is the `console.log` validation, not the `if` statement. This should work:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (location?.state?.fromPageA === null) {
  navigate('/pageA')
 }
}, []);
```

If you are not using the optional chaining, you can do:

```
useEffect(() => {
 if (location){
   if(location.state){
     if(!location.state.fromPageA){
        navigate('/pageA')
     }
   }
 }
}, []);
```

Assuming you are destructuring the `location` as `props` in the component constructor. Otherwise, use `props.location`.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to an answer that you posted on here for a similar question. Turns out I was supposed to use location.state instead of location.state.fromPageA to check for null. And also for Vercel's SSR I had to set the state of it instead of rendering the value directly into the UI. Thanks!